# DataView.ListChanged event triggered improperly even when property value of DataRow is not modified

Tags: c#, datatable, dataview, listchanged

I have a DataTable and i have listened the **DataTable.DefaultView.ListChanged** event for my changes and upon data updates, ListChanged event is fired improperly when updating same value for the existing DataRow.

Here, upon updating DataRow with same value, ListChanged event is triggered with **ListChangedType.ItemChanged**. But i believe the event should be triggered only if any property of the DataRow is modified.

```
public DataTable GetTestingDataTable()
{
   DataTable collection = new DataTable();
   collection.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
   collection.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
   collection.Rows.Add(1001, "Value1");
   collection.Rows.Add(1002, "Value2");

   collection.DefaultView.ListChanged += OnDefaultViewListChanged;
   return collection;
}

private void OnDefaultViewListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dataTable = GetTestingDataTable();
    // Lets say value in dataTable.Rows[0]["ID"] is 100.
    // User didn't know what value exists in DataRow and provides 100 as value, which is same from another user interface. (Users application)
    dataTable.Rows[0]["ID"] = 100; // This triggers ListChanged event.
}
```

Comment: You are changing the value by putting the row on the left side of the equal sign.  Try dataTable.Rows[0]["ID"]; which just reads the row.

Comment: Guys - I have update the snippet with reason for updating the same value in DataRow.

Comment: "i believe the event should be triggered only if any property of the DataRow is modified." - and so it was. The fact that *you* consider the value to be the same and *you* want to ignore it doesn't mean that a good, well built control that has to cater to millions of use cases should ignore such changes.

Comment: E.g. consider `dataTable.Rows[0]["Value"] = "value1";`. I don't know whether you consider that a change or not because I don't know whether you think it's case sensitive or not. And nor does the control know what is or isn't important to you.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - We can include codes to check for the modified value from input. We just needed a confirmation, why framework can't detect the changes before triggering event.